# How to mark the child instance in React that you want to render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What's the best way to mark the child's instance in this case?  My child in the return is inside of an Array.map() loop, along with the button. And when I hit the button to show tge child, all the copies show up. How can i get the specific individual child to show?

```
state = {
        isLoading: true,
        team: [],
        error: null,
        isHidden: true
      }
    toggleHidden () {
      this.setState({
        isHidden: !this.state.isHidden
      })
    }
```

Inside the map:

```
 <span class="arrow" onClick={this.toggleHidden.bind(this)}>click</span>
                        {!this.state.isHidden && <p>{s.description}</p>}
```

Comment: what collection are you mapping? team?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using bind or arrow functions in render, since it is an anti pattern. Every time you will rerender a new function will be created, of course this is for larger scale applications. Since this is out of the way and without seeing all of your code I believe you need something like that:

```
<span class="arrow" onClick={()=>this.toggleHidden(itemfromArray.id)}>click</span>
                        {!this.state.isHidden && <p>{s.description}</p>}
```

and for your class function:

```
    toggleHidden = (id) => {
      this.setState({
        yourArray: this.state.yourArray.map(item => {
          if (item.id === id){
            return {
              ...item,
              'isHidden': !item['isHidden']
            }
          }
          return item
        })
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the array you are mapping (i'm assuming its team) hold a property of `visibility` and an `id`.
Then pass to toggle function the id of the child you want to change its state.

```
class Comp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      team: [
        { description: "hi", id: 0, isHidden: false },
        { description: "bye", id: 1, isHidden: false }
      ],
      error: null,
      isHidden: true
    };
    this.toggleHidden = this.toggleHidden.bind(this);
  }

  toggleHidden(id) {
    let temp = Array(...this.state.team);
    let item = temp.find(t => t.id === id);
    item.isHidden = !item.isHidden;
    this.setState({
      team: temp
    });
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.team.map(s => (
      <span>
        <span class="arrow" onClick={() => this.toggleHidden(s.id)}>
          click
        </span>
        <p>{s.isHidden && s.description}</p>
      </span>
    ));
  }
}
```

[View on CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/myoq3178n9)

Comment: And what if I don't have access to the array - it's the external json file?

Comment: @MaxT what do you mean? you are mapping the array, aren't you?

Comment: In general you can read an external json file and assign it to a variable (JSONArray typed)

Comment: The array gets the fetched json data, so I can't add properties to the team

Comment: Does it make sense?

Comment: Oh.. you can iterate over that array and add a new property. Let's say you have that array: `let team= [{description:"hi"},{description:"bye"}];`
Then you can add properties:
`team.forEach((item,index)=>item.id=index; item.isHidden=false)`

Comment: You do it once you are fetching the data of course.

Comment: when I do it like so inside fetch it says "item is not defined" -    .then(data =>
            this.setState({
                team: data,
                isLoading: false,
            }),
            team.forEach((item,index)=>item.id=index, item.isHidden=false)
        )

Comment: don't do it inside the fetch. do it after fetch is done and you have the variable as is

Comment: Sorry to keep bugging but I've set it to look like this but there is still an error.

Comment: fetchTeam(item) {
     fetch(team)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data =>
            this.setState({
                team: data,
                isLoading: false,
            })
        )
        .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
        team.forEach((item,index)=>item.id=index, item.isHidden=false)
    }

Comment: says Cannot set property 'isHidden' of undefined

Comment: Well.. team is inside the state. so you should refer it with this.state.team. But if you want to setState with new array you'll need to copy it.. so after the fetch is done. do: `let tempteam  = this.state.team.slice();` and after that: `tempteam.forEach((item,index)=>item.id=index, item.isHidden=false))`, then: `this.setState({team: tempteam});`

Comment: also, looks like your sandbox also shows the same word even if you click on different buttons, so there is something wrong

Comment: In sendbox it shows the descriptions which they are different. (hi and bye). 
About the error... I'll need to see the code on sendbox or something like that.

Comment: Hi, i fixed your code. you had a problem with the fetch. you fetched the data wrong. and you got an error. Look at this now: https://codesandbox.io/s/wwv09k81jw